# Use a counter as label

Tags: counters, labels, automation

I want to set the value of a counter as a label.

I have the following structure:

```
\section{First Section}  
Some text  
\subsection{First Subsection}  
Text again
\subsection{Second Subsection}
Another Text
```

And I want the (sub)sections labeled with its number. Like:

```
\section{First Section}  
\label{1}  
Some text  
\subsection{First Subsection}  
\label{1.1}  
Text again
\subsection{Second Subsection}  
\label{1.2}
Another Text
```

Is there a way to automatically set a label after every section, subsection with its number?

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) It is possible to set this up but I would rather advise against it: The idea of a label is precisely to _decouple_ it from a counter. What happens if you add a subsection somewhere? All labels would change. Definitely not meaningful. IMHO, of course...

Comment: I am using latex to make a pdf-file of my notes taken at university. The prof is referencing like "as shown in § 1.2". Any idea how to solve this in a better way?

Comment: @R.Schlegel Just do `\subsection{Ducks}\label{subsec:ducks}` and type `as shown in~\S\ref{subsec:ducks}`. Choose a meaningful label; “automatic labeling” means “no labeling at all”.

Comment: the whole point of using `\label` is to _not_ use teh printed number so if you add a section and change all the numbering, all cross references still work. never generate the label and avoid using digits in the label, as your `\label{1.1}` works but will be confusing to you if later that actually references section 2.2

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341948/a-good-strategy-for-labeling-sections-equations-figures-or-tables

Comment: This question is confusing. In some lines the counters should be set from labels, in other lines labels should be set from labels. The O.P. wasn't online since the day of posting, so this question is pretty much of being abandoned!