# How can one label equations automatically?

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath, labels

While using the "equation" environment, is there any way to get the equation number of the current environment?

What I had in mind was, I create some sort of function \func that returns the displayed number of the current equation, so I can put it in my \label{eq:\func} somehow.

Can anyone please tell me if this is possible?
Thanks.

Comment: the whole point of `\label` is that you do not need to know the number. What is your use case here? `\label` should be an internal identifier like `\label{fermat}` it should not be related to the number used

Comment: if you have an auto-generated label it is unusable as you would not know what string to use for `\ref`

Comment: But to answer your question: `\theequation`.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341948/a-good-strategy-for-labeling-sections-equations-figures-or-tables/341953